# Set mysql user host in jdbc connection java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to remote mysql server in java, from ip 111.111.111.111 to ip 111.111.111.222 with JDBC connector:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+serverAddress+":3306/" + this.dBName + "?" + "user=" + this.userName + "&password=" + this.password + "");
```

- user@111.111.111.111 is created in database and GRANTS are working fine.
- user@localhost doesn't exist in database because I think is not neccesary.
- Firewall is allowing connection.

For some reason when I try to start the connection an exception is  generated:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('user'@'localhost') does not exist
```

but I'm requesting the connection from ip 111.111.111.111

**Note:** when I write an @ in the username this shows the correct host ip but with an extra @, like this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user@'@'111.111.111.111' (using password: YES)
```

So, What am I doing wrong? or how can set the host of the mysql username?

**EDIT:**

Additionally I've tested by terminal the mysql connection and it works properly: (so@SSS ip is 111.111.111.111)

```
so@SSS:~$ mysql -h 111.111.111.222 -u user -p dbname
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 85
Server version: 5.7.17 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_dbname |
+---------------------+
| wh_with_customer    |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: `user` does't have privilege to connect with mysql. You have to give `user` the permission

Comment: " because I think is not neccesary." - check your assumptions.

Comment: @duffymo because I just connect to database remotely. So is it neccesary?

Comment: try `mysql -h111.111.111.111 -uuser -p` and see whether you can access to Mysql remotely

Comment: @HaifengZhang But I'm testing mysql connection by shell and this is the result: 

`mysql -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -u user -p dbName
Enter password: 
... Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  
...
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_dbname |
+---------------------+
...| wh_with_customer    |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)`

So it really works

Comment: MySQL is telling you it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't grant privileges to `user` from my perspective

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'111.111.111.111' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Execute it and replace `PASSWORD` with your real password.

Alternatively, try using `DriverManager.getConnection(String url, String user, String password)` other than

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+serverAddress+":3306/" + this.dBName + "?" + "user=" + this.userName + "&password=" + this.password + "");
```

`DriverManager.getConnection(String url)` expects URL in `jdbc:subprotocol:subname` format, `getConnection(url, username, password)` is more precise

Comment: This is the result of:

`show grants
    -> ;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@111.111.111.%                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'111.111.111.%'                                                        |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW ON `dbname`.* TO 'user'@'111.111.111.%' |

2 rows in set (0,00 sec)`

Comment: and I just tried with `conn =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+serverAddress+":3306/" + this.dBName+"", this.userName+"" ,this.password );` but it still showing `java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('user'@'localhost') does not exist` 

But i'm not requesting from localhost but from a different ip.

Thanks @HaifengZhang

Comment: run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: It will work because the connection will be made by localhost. There is no possibility to connect remotely and set the host correctly (in this case user@111.111.111.111)? I can't find out if JDBC always create connection as localhost user.

Comment: `Access denied for user 'user@'@'111.111.111.111' `  what is the username ?  is it `user` or `user@`?  `The user specified as a definer ('user'@'localhost') does not exist ` means  `user` doesn't exist. is it possible that the username you use is misspelling?

Comment: Is my English so bad? :S well, Username is "user" but when I type in connection parameters user@ the exception throws: `Access denied for user 'user@'@'111.111.111.111'`. As you cann see JDBC shows me the client IP which is what I want, connecting as **user@111.111.111.111** When I type the correct username JDBC tries to connect as **user@localhost**, but it isn't the user I created.

The question now is: Can I set the clienthost ip manually or set a flag to connect from my IP or JDBC always tries to connect as user@**localhost**??